# need help in apache solr suggester for phrases

Tags: search, solr, autocomplete, autosuggest, search-suggestion

i am trying to use suggeter in my application

example: I have a documents as below

```html
apache solr version 4.2
apache hadoop version 2
cassendra nosql db
mysql rdbms
```

if i search for "apa" first two result is shown as suggestion and 
if the search string is "apache so" only 1st one is shown as suggestion which is as expected

But

if i search for "solr" no result is shown for suggestion( i would expect apache solr version 4.2)

My query is

http://localhost:8983/solr/colletion/suggest?wt=json&indent=true&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.q=solr

below is my field type

```html
 <fieldType name="text_general2" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
 <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

and suggest request handler in solrconfig.xml is

```html
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">suggest</str>
      <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
     <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.WFSTLookupFactory</str>
     <str name="field">title2</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
      <float name="threshold">0</float>   
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
  <requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">8</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

my solr version is 4.2 CDH 4.7

please help

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `KeywordTokenizerFactory` which treats the entire string as a single stream. So in your case, the 1st document would be indexed as

```
apache solr version 4.2
```

Since your auto suggest is turned on, your first query `apac` & others starting with the same prefix  `apac` can match both the entries in index starting with it (as you have `suggest` turned on)

If you looking to match **individual words** in a text you should consider using another Tokenizer such as `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`.

More details: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory

Comment: Thanks for response ....I have tried that. If i search for "apa" it ll give response as "apache" . But what i need is when i search for "apache so" i need response as "apache solr version 4.2" and if i search for "solr" it should also return "apache solr version 4.2".